# How to position ionic button using CSS

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to position a button to center of screen. But it looks like there's an offset of 20px to the button.It appears 20px vertically away from the exact center.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Here's the html body:

```
<body ng-app="starter" class="platform-ios platform-cordova platform-webview">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-content>
          <div  id="cool-button-div">
          <button class="button button-block button-calm">Cool!</button>
          </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

and CSS:

```
  #cool-button-div {

    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:50%;

}
```

I can position the button by calculating the exact center of screen and if I use `top : 250px`, it works but if I use `top:50%` it doesnt work.

Note: I do not want to use additional divs which act like spacer views.

Comment: I guess you are trying to position it to the middle (top-bottom) of the screen, and not center (left-right) of the screen. Right?

Comment: Margin :auto made div horizontally center , hence I'm looking at vertically centre

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **vh** unit will help you. Please use **vh**.

**css:-**

```
#cool-button-div {

    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:50vh;

}
```

Comment: Cool. I always want to avoid placing additional divs. Though it worked, can you add some additional reference on vh ?

Comment: Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh

Comment: Thanks for quick response!